# Different behaviour of LINQ-Sum and manual adding of integer values

Tags: c#, linq, int

What could be the reason for the different behaviour of this:

```
int temp = 2147483647;
Console.WriteLine(temp + 1); //returns -2147483648 

List<int> ltemp = new List<int>() { 2147483647, 1 };
Console.WriteLine(ltemp.Sum()); //returns OverFlowException
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Enumerable.Sum` is implemented with calculating sum with `checked` keyword.

[checked (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

It is using the following code- [Source Reference - Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#47c6324656bd90c5):

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    int sum = 0;
    checked {
        foreach (int v in source) sum += v;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you do the same with:

```
checked
{
    int temp = 2147483647;
    Console.WriteLine(temp + 1); //returns -2147483648
}
```

You will get the same exception

Comment: And of course, in C#, non-constant expressions are `unchecked` by default. +1

Comment: Well, the default is really outside C#, it's up to the compiler.